# Next day X at Y

Tags: java, date, calendar

I need to schedule tasks based on times and days the user inputs. These tasks repeat every week, and based on checkbox values I need to set them enabled on those days.

For example, it's Wednesday the sixth 15:40 UTC+2 at the moment. If the user wants to schedule a task every Wednesday at 12:00, I want to get the time in milliseconds on the thirteenth of November at 12:00. If the task is set to be scheduled at 16:00 every Wednesday, I want the time today. Task scheduled to run on every Thursday results in the millisecond representation of tomorrow. So, basically the closest date that is coming. How do I implement this in Java?

Comment: What is your attempt so far ?

Comment: Take a look at [Quartz Scheduler library](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)

Comment: @PaulLo I was asking how to get the date, not how to schedule. I'm developing the program for Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deprecated [Date.getDay()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDay%28%29) function explains how to do this using Calendar. (Date still works if you really want to use it despite being deprecated).

`Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);`

Process-wise, you would have a class for storing the event's day of a week as an int, and the time.

Then, you would evaluate today's date and time for the following:

1. Evaluate whether or not today is the specified day of the week. 
   If it is, check whether or not the time has already passed. 
   If it hasn't, schedule it logically for today at that time.
   If it has, add 7 days to the calendar date to get the expected date.
2. Otherwise, if the scheduled day of the week is before today's day of the week:
   Subtract the difference between the two days from 7. (i.e. if target day is Sunday (0) and today is Wednesday (3), 7 - (3 - 0) = 4, therefore add 4 days to today's date to get target date)
3. If it's after, just calculate the difference between the two days (i.e. if the target day is Saturday (6) and today is Wednesday (3), 6 - 3 = 3, therefore add 3 days to today's date to get the target date).

You may also need to check for DST.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I posted my implementation below.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest, and maybe cheekiest, answer is to use Quartz. :)

http://quartz-scheduler.org/

You can of course write your own scheduler, but this is not a trivial task.

**Edit**

To get the date, you can use the add() method on the calendar.
To get the time in ms, you can use the method getTimeInMillis().

If you want a much easier (and in my humble opinion, much more intuitive) approach you can use the DateTime class from joda-time ( http://www.joda.org/joda-time/ ) which are more elegant, immutable and timezone aware. :)

Good luck.

Comment: It is not a big deal to write your own scheduler with java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService. Of course it depends on the requirements.

Comment: I was asking how to get the date, not how to schedule. I'm developing the program for Android.

Comment: If you by scheduler mean "Tread pool that sleeps deterministically" then sure. But that's not usually how one would use the word "scheduler". I would think that one main requirement would be the ability to change and persist schedules. But yeah, it's hard to tell from the question. :)

Comment: Android has it's own `AlarmManager` to schedule tasks. This is not a problem, but I was just wondering how to find out the closest datetime that matches the criterias.

Comment: I have updated my answer to more accurately try and answer your question. I hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering. Compass' answer was correct and I created the following implementation in Java:

```
public static long nextDate(int day, int hour, int minute) {
    // Initialize the Calendar objects
    Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar target  = Calendar.getInstance();

    // Fetch the current day of the week. 
    // Calendar class weekday indexing starts at 1 for Sunday, 2 for Monday etc. 
    // Change it to start from zero on Monday continueing to six for Sunday
    int today = target.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 2;
    if(today == -1) today = 7;

    int difference = -1;
    if(today <= day) {
        // Target date is this week
        difference = day - today;
    } else {
        // Target date is passed already this week.
        // Let's get the date next week
        difference = 7 - today + day;
    }

    // Setting the target hour and minute
    target.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    target.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    target.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    // If difference == 0 (target day is this day), let's check that the time isn't passed today. 
    // If it has, set difference = 7 to get the date next week
    if(difference == 0 && current.getTimeInMillis() > target.getTimeInMillis()) {
        difference = 7;
    }

    // Adding the days to the target Calendar object
    target.add(Calendar.DATE, difference);

    // Just for debug
    System.out.println(target.getTime());

    // Return the next suitable datetime in milliseconds
    return target.getTimeInMillis();
}
```